# spresense sdkでgpioピンの役割を変更する方法

Tags: spresense

spresense初心者です。spresense sdkを使用して、arduino IDEのsoftware serialのように違うGPIOピンでserial通信のポートを増やしたい場合、どのような方法が考えられるでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spresense SDKの中に、SPIのbitbangは見つけましたがSerialのbitbangは用意されてなさそうです(たぶん)。ですので、Software Serialを行う場合は自作するか、どこかからもってきて移植するかしかないですね(たぶん)
https://github.com/pfalcon/uart-bitbang
https://github.com/adrianomarto/soft_uart
もしくはSpresense ArduinoのSoftware Serialライブラリを持ってきてSDKへ移植する方が早いのかもしれません。

ただ、SpresenseのSerial端子は、Arduino UNOと違って、シリアルモニタ用のSerialとは独立して、メインボード/拡張ボード側に別のUART2(Serial2)端子が出ているのでそれが使えます。PCとの接続であれば、拡張ボード側のUSB端子でUSBSerialライブラリというものを見つけたのでこれも使えそうです。これはArduino用のライブラリですが、
https://qiita.com/baggio/items/e62cb26630fdb78881f2
SDKであればこちらですね。
https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense/tree/master/sdk/system/cdcacm

gpioの叩き方は、こちらが参考になると思います。
https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense/blob/master/sdk/system/gpio/gpio_main.c

シンプルにboard_gpio_read(), board_gpio_write() 関数を使って読み書きができると思います。

ピンの役割をGPIOに設定する必要があるので、board_gpio_config()でmodeを0に設定する必要がありそうです。

たぶんこんな感じ(間違っていたらどなたかご指摘をお願いします^^;

<<読み出しの場合>>
board_gpio_config(PIN_XXX, 0, true, true, PIN_FLOAT);
と設定しておいて、
value = board_gpio_read(PIN_XXX, 0, true, true, PIN_FLOAT);
で 1 or 0 が読み出せる

<<書き込みの場合>>
board_gpio_config(PIN_XXX, 0, false, true, PIN_FLOAT);
と設定しておいて、
board_gpio_write(PIN_XXX, 1 or 0);
で 1 or 0 の書き込みができる

ピン番号はpin.hに定義されています
https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense/blob/master/sdk/bsp/include/arch/chip/pin.h

ご参考まで。