# spresense SDKでGPIOピンをシリアル通信用に設定したい

Tags: spresense

spresense sdkを使用しています。
arduinoのsoftware serialのようにGPIOピンでserial通信を行いたい場合はどうすればいいでしょうか？

・spresenseメイン基板+LTE拡張ボード
接続するデバイスのインターフェース電圧の都合上、メイン基板上のUARTは使用できません。

Comment: こちらの記事と同件かもしれませんね。[spresense sdkでgpioピンの役割を変更する方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/60027/26370) そしてこちらは類似の話題でしょうか。[Spresense Arduino ソフトウェアシリアル 通信速度について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/71401/26370)

Answer (score 0):

spresense 側から見て受信端子 (RXD) は gpio 汎用入力
spresense 側から見て出力端子 (TXD) は gpio 汎用出力
にするだけです。あとはソフトウエアのほうで頑張る。

spresense ぢゃない昔の 8bit マイコンでソフトウエアシリアル作ったけど超絶面倒というか、手間のわりに性能出なくて泣きそうとか、あまりお勧めしないです。

電圧違いなだけなら電圧変換 IC 入れるだけっスよ？ソフトのコスト（維持期間）を考えると、回路作っちゃうほうがコスト（設計時間）かからない可能性が高いです。 RS232 ドライバ IC も要は電圧変換 IC なわけだし。

Answer (score 0):

[LTE拡張ボードの回路図](https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense-hw-design-files/raw/master/CXD5602PWBLM1/schematics/CXD5602PWBLM1_schematics_en.pdf)を見ると、
R45,R46の抵抗を外して、R44,R47をショートすれば、LTE拡張ボードのピンヘッダにUART信号を出すことができそうです。（試してみたことは無いですが）
[image: LTE拡張ボード]

UARTの通信だけを行うのであればソフトウェアシリアルでも良いですが、
他の処理も同時に動かすのであれば、私もソフトウェアシリアルはお勧めしないです。